# Semantic UI - Search Selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the Semantic UI - Search Selection, but it's not working.

I got the code from their website ([here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html)) but it does nothing...

Code:

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="country">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="ad"><i class="ad flag"></i>Andorra</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ae"><i class="ae flag"></i>United Arab Emirates</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even if I initialize it on jQuery it doesn't work:

```
jQuery('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there something else I need to do to make it to work on WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it using `class="simple"`:

`<div class="ui fluid search selection simple dropdown">`